# Name resolution without providing the FQDN, but I can't control what DNS suffixes get appended to my queries

Tags: domain-name-system, fqdn

I have a virtual laboratory in which I have setup a domain controller that handles all DNS queries for my domain (x.domain - I have full control over this), and it also contains stub zones for all the other domains (a.local, b.local, c.local - all are managed by the company and I do not have access to change anything on their DCs). I am using this virtual DC as my primary DNS of my physical computer, which is a member of the a.local domain.

A domain GPO is applied to my physical computer and it determines which DNS suffixes get appended to my single label DNS queries: sitelocal, a.local, b.local, c.local. I do not have access to modify these suffixes, and yet I would like to have name resolution to my x.domain without providing the FQDN.

Is there any way for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to control the DNS Suffix Search Order. When that is specified, the client appends the DNS Suffix(es) to single label names, which is what you don't want. You want to resolve single label names. Windows DNS Server can optionally perform single label name resolution, but the client needs to send a query for a single label name, which your client is not doing.

Answer (score 0):

Using standard DNS zone files you could write a file with records (A, CNAME, etc.) with relative paths (without a leading dot) and then import that file from other zones with the directive $INCLUDE as you can see [here](https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/include.html)

I have little experience with Windows DNS, but I have checked that it supports the standard DNS zone file format (at least to export data) and I have seen that PowerShell is able to manage zone files. If this does not work, you could use other DNS servers to complement (through redirections) Windows DNS